# Netbeans Java EJB Stateful Session Bean Strange exception between interface and implementing class

Tags: java, session, servlets, netbeans, stateful

I'm working on the connection between servlet and stateful session bean. Here's the code:

```
@Stateful(mappedName = "ejb/SFSession")
public class SFSession implements SFSessionRemote {

    private String name;

    public SFSession() {
        this.name = "";
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "" ;
    }
}
```

And the interface:

```
@Remote
public interface SFSessionRemote {
    public String getName();

}
```

I'm keep getting the strange error(bug) which looks like: `[some path...]/SFSession.java:23: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override`

This i weird as it actually overrides the function properly, doesn't it? When I pass the empty interface and class as well it works ok and I can import it in my servlet. But when I write a method in the interface(or in class) and override it in class(in the second case expose it to the class), it breaks. In fact I even used built in tools in netbeans to do it, what makes it even more annoying. Does anyone have any idea on this one? If necessary I'll post some other files from my project(I just think they don't count here). Please help.

Comment: clean your code and re-buld, you should be alrite.

Comment: tried it a few times in different combinations, also restarting IDE and stuff like that